# How can i change the volume of applications?

Tags: android

when i press the physical volume button in the edges of the phone to change the volume of applications( my app is running, and no sound is playing in this app), but it does change the system volume(ringtones vollum).

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: If you don't have any sound in your app, why do you want it to change the volume of the app? It has no use.

Comment: no . i have a lot of sound to play in this app, but i want to change  vollum of this application whenerver i press the physical volume button in the edges of the phone